# Packaging spring application in executable jar causes 'Failed to read schema document'

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I have packaged a spring application into executable jar with following pom.xml/maven configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.some.Main
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now when I execute this generated jar it gives following WARN

```
Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

and execution fails with exception

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 70; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans:beans'.
```

And same application executes well when run without jar packaging in eclipse. I am sure it is not dependency issue, I have provided appropriate dependencies.
Issue happens due to packaging into jar.
Please help, thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use spring-boot-maven-plugin to build jar? The below is sample.

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass> com.some.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Thank you @jacky-neo 
Using spring boot plugin to package jar solved issue for me. Although still not able to figure out root cause of issue while using maven packaging plugin.

Comment: be glad to hear from that u resovle issue. spring boot app is fat jar. so we always use spring plugin to build jar. apache maven plugin needs more setting to finish job that you want.  I do not know it any more too. I used apache plugin to add some third jar into spring boot app jars when it can not be downloaded from maven repository.